# Next Page on click by page based application

Tags: ipad, ios6, uibutton

In my page based application i want to perform the operation next page on click of button?Is it possible to to go next page using button in page based application?Pls help me to solve this issue

Edit: My application like story book im showing set of images in pages while turning next page, i want to show the nxt page by click

Comment: Please provide some other info like the structure of application, used view controllers, etc.

Comment: so you are uses the UIPageViewController to show the images as pages, right?

Comment: @Wolvorin YES UIPageViewController to show the images as pages

Comment: I don't  have enough knowledge about it but it is possible. May be using the custom view animation :)

Comment: May I can know the structure of the application? ie hierarchy of the views ?

Comment: In my app it is one root view (conformes to `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`)> one Dataview and Modelcontrol(conforms to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` of kind `NSObject`) as the datasource. Is this is your hierarchy of UIViewControllers?

Comment: If so I have one solution to your problem :)

Comment: On click of buttons you can navigate to the next and previous page easily :)

Comment: I do the same in my application too

Comment: Please give me the information about the hierarchy of your application view Controllers.

Comment: Just have to call the Page view controller's data source methods on click of the buttons

Comment: Hi have you get any solution? does my solution is helpful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your app the class conforms to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol, make one object of this class in root view controller suppose `ModelController` then the object is `_modelController`.
2. Then in root view controller just put two `UIButton` connect them with appropriate `IBAction` methods suppose for previous button `previousClick:` and for next button `nextClick:`.
3. Now the code for each method is as follow:

   `-(IBAction)previousClick:(id)sender { [_modelController pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:_dataViewController]; }`

   `-(IBAction)nextClick:(id)sender { [_modelController pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:_dataViewController]; }`

Here I suppose that the `pageViewController` is the one object of type `UIPageViewController` and is one of the declared and synthesized variable of root view controller, and also same for the `_dataViewController` which is one `UIViewController` contains one `UIImageView` to present the images on the root view.

**EDIT**

This also can be done with the using the `DataViewController` for that all the logic have to move to that view controller and all so the references must be needed for the `UIPageViewController` and `ModelController`.